# CSS or HTML: Link or Anchor to Image Coordinates

Tags: html, css, image

What I am trying to do is similar to an image map - in reverse. I have a large image (over 2000x2000) and want to give links to coordinates on the image.  There are items in the image that I would like users to be able to jump directly to with having to scan over the whole image manually. Is this possible with either CSS or HTML by adding links to coordinates or adding anchors to the image? I would use js if that was an option as well.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  The notion of jumping to a position on a web browser window is limited in general.  Here are some general possibilities, without specific implementation details:

1. You could treat it as a sprite image, and use JavaScript/jQuery to change the image coordinates so that the point of the image you are interested in moves to the the top left of a div positioned on the page.  But the portion of the image above and to the left of that point would not be visible.
2. You could define it as a background image in a div, and define an invisible table or invisible fixed-position divs within that div, and link to specific divs or cells in that overlay.  In this case, a y-coordinate in the image where the div or cell is positioned would probably move to the top of the browser window, but horizontal positioning would be problematic.  If the div or cell you target is off the screen to the right or left, the page would shift to expose it, but I don't thing that you could guarantee where the specific x-coordinate would be positioned.  Also, if the target is near the bottom of the web page, that target point will not move to the top.  But this solution wouldn't require JavaScript/jQuery - it would just mean linking to element ID's on the page.
3. This is almost the same as #2... You could overlay the image with divs and/or a table at higher z-levels, and link to those divs or table cells.
4. You could use JavaScript/jQuery to position a fixed-size div with visible borders so that its upper-left corner is at the position in the image that you are interested in.  I think you'd still have to link to that div in order to make sure that it is visible in the current viewport.
5. You should be able to lay out a form over the image and move the cursor to fields on the form. I think that the form could be transparent so that the cursor appears to be moving around on the image.  But you'd need be confident that the data entry cursor is sufficiently visible on top of the image to be useful.